# delete parent entity throws org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

So I have two tables: *projectStatus* and *projectStatusHistory*.
When a new project is created, a new record is inserted in projectStatus table. Once the project is started or status changed, a record will be inserted into projectStatusHistory table (the content of the record is from projectStatus table) and then project status is updated  in projectStatus table. When a project is complete, we will archive the last record to history table and the projectStatus table will no longer have a record for the project.

but `projectStatusRepository.delete(projectStatusId)` throws an exception

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKIB57NUSJBIJ4K8G83MFNY6V06 ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projectStatus", schema = "test")
public class ProjectStatus {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProjectStatusId id;
    
    @Column(name = "projectName", nullable = false)
    private String projectName;
    
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createDate;
    
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "statusUpdateDate", nullable = false)
    private Date statusUpdateDate;  

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "projectStatus")
    private List<projectStatusHistory> history;
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class ProjectStatusId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "projectName", nullable = false)
    private String projectName;
    
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createDate;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projectStatusHistory", schema = "test")
public class ProjectStatusHistory {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProjectStatusHistoryId id;
    
    @Column(name = "projectName", nullable = false)
    private String projectName;
    
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createDate;
    
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "statusUpdateTimeStamp", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date statusUpdateTimeStamp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "projectName", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "createDate", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    private ProjectStatus projectStatus;

}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class ProjectStatusHistoryId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "projectName", nullable = false)
    private String projectName;
    
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createDate;

    @Column(name = "statusUpdateTimeStamp", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date statusUpdateTimeStamp;
}
```

```
public interface ProjectStatusRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectStatus, ProjectStatusId> {
}
```

```
public interface ProjectStatusHistoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectStatusHistory, ProjectStatusHistoryId> {
}
```

```
public void projectStatusChanged(ProjectStatusId projectStatusId){
    ProjectStatus projectStatus =  projectStatusRepository.findById(projectStatusId);
    //move current status to history table and then update status 
    projectStatusHistory = createANewProjectStatusHistoryFromProjectStatus(projectStatus);
    projectStatus.status = newStatus;
    projectStatus.History = projectStatusHistory;
    projectStatusRepository.save(projectStatus);
}

public void projectComplete(ProjectStatusId projectStatusId){
    ProjectStatus projectStatus =  projectStatusRepository.findById(projectStatusId);
    //move current status to history table and then update status 
    projectStatusHistory = createANewProjectStatusHistoryFromProjectStatus(projectStatus);
    projectStatusHistoryRepository.save(projectStatusHistory);
    projectStatusRepository.delete(projectStatusId);
}
```

Comment: You cannot delete `ProjectStatus` entity because it has foreign keys established with your child entities `ProjectStatusHistory`. So that constraint is not allowing you to delete the parent because it would leave the children orphan.

Comment: Having two relations with an identical sequence of attributes may be a modelling problem to begin with.

Comment: @code_mechanic  this is working in DB2 but not in H2

Comment: I have never used DB2 so not sure, have you created the db yourself there ? and may have missed the foreign key constraint, may be.

Comment: No, I did not create db2 tables,

Comment: I was thinking to remove the foreign key contraints form h2,  but not sure why this is the issue b/c in my sql script for h2, I did not create foreign keys